# Isotope Filter & Sort with Onhashchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filtering

I have a website that displays various floor plans in different categories and the filter and sort from Isotope is perfect for displaying them.  I have it working just fine but what I would like to do is add onhashchange so when they click on a floor plan and go to that page and then go back to the original page they don't lose the previous filters and sorts they have applied.

My problem is I have code that I can get the onhashchange to work with the filter but not the sort and I lose my onpageload filter.  On initial page load I only want those plans which I have tagged with a class of all to show (this is really important).

I have a fiddle of for each, this is the fiddle with the onhashchange working on the filter but not the sort and I can not seem to get the element-items with the class of all to be the only ones that load on page load https://jsfiddle.net/h8gv9gh6/

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    getSortData: {
      name: '.name',
      symbol: '.symbol'
    }
  });

  // bind sort button click
  $('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
    $container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });
});

// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match( /ium$/ );
  }
};

function getHashFilter() {
  // get filter=filterName
  var matches = location.hash.match( /filter=([^&]+)/i );
  var hashFilter = matches && matches[1];
  return hashFilter && decodeURIComponent( hashFilter );
}

$( function() {

  var $grid = $('.grid');

  // bind filter button click
  var $filterButtonGroup = $('.filter-button-group');
  $filterButtonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterAttr = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // set filter in hash
    location.hash = 'filter=' + encodeURIComponent( filterAttr );
  });

  var isIsotopeInit = false;

  function onHashchange() {
    var hashFilter = getHashFilter();
    if ( !hashFilter && isIsotopeInit ) {
      return;
    }
    isIsotopeInit = true;
    // filter isotope
    $grid.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.element-item',
      layoutMode: 'fitRows',
      // use filterFns
      filter: filterFns[ hashFilter ] || hashFilter
    });
    // set selected class on button
    if ( hashFilter ) {
      $filterButtonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $filterButtonGroup.find('[data-filter="' + hashFilter + '"]').addClass('is-checked');
    }
  }

  $(window).on( 'hashchange', onHashchange );

  // trigger event handler to init Isotope
  onHashchange();
});
```

Here is my other fiddle where the sort and filter work as well as my onpageload filter of all but I have no onhashchange: https://jsfiddle.net/0kgavwud/

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    getSortData: {
      name: '.name',
      symbol: '.symbol'
    }
  });

var PageLoadFilter = '.all';
  $container.isotope({ filter: PageLoadFilter});
  // filter functions
  var filterFns = {
    // show if number is greater than 50
    numberGreaterThan50: function() {
      var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
      return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
    },
    // show if name ends with -ium
    ium: function() {
      var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
      return name.match( /ium$/ );
    }
  };

  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });

  // bind sort button click
  $('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
    $container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

});
```

Is there a way to to get onhashchange working with sort and an initial page load filter?